# Batch: Run an Awk-Script on all text-files in the folder

Tags: batch-file

basically I want to run the following command on every text-file automatically:

```
awk -f myScript.awk file1.txt > new\file1.txt
awk -f myScript.awk file2.txt > new\file2.txt
...
```

Then move the processed files to the folder \old.

```
move *.txt \old
```

should work for that part.

How do I create the correct for-loop, so that the output of the awk program has the same name as the input, just in the new folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, try this:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do awk -f myScript.awk "%%~fi" > "new\%%~nxi"
```

Comment: Hi, not sure what the %%~fi and %%~nxi mean.

Comment: I used for %%i in (*.txt) do (awk -f myScripst.awk "%%i" > new\"%%i") and it works. Thanks.

Comment: `%%~fi` is the full file name of `%%i` without double quotes. `%%~nxi` is the file name without path and double quotes. For help, type `help for`:)